# (PDOException(code: 0): could not find driver - Debian Ubuntu Server - error only occurs when running Laravel queue using redis

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis

I have a Laravel application running on Ubuntu Dedian Server, running php 8.1. Certain tasks are scheduled and I get the error (PDOException(code: 0): could not find driver, mysql_pdo is installed and enabled in php ini file.
I use redis database for the Laravel queue connection, I have to due to the volume of the task.
I have checked all paths in the php ini and am certain they are all setup correctly.

The Laravel Application runs without problems otherwise, it is only my queues that are giving me the error.

I have ensure mysql_pdo is installed and restarted the server afterwards. I have checked the php ini files that is loaded using phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by restarting my supervisor that was running on the server.